# Adding custom namespace to metadata (BitmapMetadata)

Tags: c#, wpf, adobe, metadata, xmp

Here's a quick question: how to correctly add a custom namespace to XMP using `BitmapMetadata`?

Let's say I want the namespace to look like this: `xmlns:MyNamespace="http://test"`

There's no clear way how to add the namespace in the `BitmapMetadata`, so I tried this:

```
//I retrieve the image frame (Frame[0]), then:
var metadata = (BitmapMetadata) frame.Metadata.Clone();

//Covering all bases
metadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/PaddingSchema:Padding", 4096);
metadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/PaddingSchema:Padding", 4096);
metadata.SetQuery("/xmp/PaddingSchema:Padding", 4096);
```

And now the main query, I tried going the 'obvious way':

```
metadata.SetQuery("/xmp/MyNamespace:MyTag", "AwesomeTagValue");
```

And sure enough, if I save the image, open it and run

```
var value = (string) metadata.GetQuery("/xmp/MyNamespace:MyTag");
```

it returns the correct value - AwesomeTagValue.

Here's the problem though, the tags are written to the file with malformed namespace.
I peeked into the file and here's the stripped XML/RDF view:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:prefix0="MyNamespace"> ... </rdf:Description>
```

so all the tags are prefixed with `prefix0` and I'd like it to be

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:MyNamespace="http://test"> ... </rdf:Description>
```

Any ideas how to do that or if it's even possible with `BitmapMetadata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can achieve with `BitmapMetadata`:

```
<rdf:Description xmlns:prefix0="http://test">...</rdf:Description>
```

Here is the metadata query:

```
metadata.SetQuery("/xmp/{wstr=http://test}:MyTag", "AwesomeTagValue");
```

According to documentation:

> If there is no friendly schema prefix for a particular schema, for
>   example if an image contains XMP metadata using a custom third party
>   schema, the metadata query should use the full schema URL.

So if you are not satisfied with the result you could:

- Open the image file and replace all `prefix0` with `MyNamespace`
- Use a third party library to modify metadata

Comment: thanks for solution it worked for me but i cant set something like    <xmpRights:UsageTerms>
    <rdf:Alt>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Cleared for associated television programme publicity including print and online for:- Television - Scheduled linear services</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Alt>
   </xmpRights:UsageTerms>