# Jpeg writing xmp for null property

Tags: c#, metadata, jpeg, photoshop, xmp

I have a program which can read xmp Data in C# but some images have some properties NULL and when I am trying to write xmp data for a NULL property it gives an exception:

> Property cannot be found :Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F40

Is it possible to set values for properties which are NULL?

```
// Credit Status = Copyrighted
metaData.SetQuery("/xmp/xmpRights:Marked", "True");

//overwriting instructions with static text
metaData.SetQuery("/xmp/photoshop:Instructions", Constants.InstructionsText);

var usageTerms = metaData.GetQuery("/xmp/xmpRights:UsageTerms/x-default");

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(usageTerms)))
    metaData.SetQuery("/xmp/xmpRights:UsageTerms/x-default", Constants.UsageTermText);
```

Basically i need a script through which i can create a new XMP property in Jpeg?

Comment: May be helpfull: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/can-not-remove-jpg-tags-error-0x88982f40 and http://www.digicamhelp.com/camera-logs/random-thoughts/removing-tags-in-vista-windows-photo-gallery/

Comment: Try to get names of the images have which have properties NULL - Whats wrong with this images?

Comment: basically i need a script through which i can create an xmp property in Jpeg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758054/adding-custom-namespace-to-metadata-bitmapmetadata this link suggest how to add but i am unable to do for Rights Usage Terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way, I hope it helps!
I found the answer on [MSDN comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata(v=vs.90))

```
if (!metadata.ContainsQuery(@"/xmp/photoshop:Instructions"))
     metadata.SetQuery(@"/xmp/{wstr=http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/}:Instructions", instructions);
if (metadata.ContainsQuery("/xmp/photoshop:Marked"))
     metadata.SetQuery(@"/xmp/{wstr=http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/}:Marked", CreditStatus);
if (metadata.ContainsQuery("/xmp/xmpRights:UsageTerms/x-default"))
{
     metadata.SetQuery(@"/xmp/{wstr=http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/}:UsageTerms",
                                          new BitmapMetadata("xmpalt"));
     metadata.SetQuery(@"/xmp/xmpRights:UsageTerms/x-default", usageTerms);
}
```